# How to place container over a div?

Tags: html, css

This question might sound weird, but here's the code:

```css
body{
    background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
}
.inside-box {
    border: 15px solid rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
    height: 95vh;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 1);

  }
  
.outside-box {
    background: rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);

  }
  .flex-container-top {
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-top">     
    </div>
    <div class="outside-box">
     <div class="inside-box"></div>
    </div>
```

Sorry I don't know how to show code here properly, but what I have is this:

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMT3B.png)

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDfY.png)

Don't worry a lot about sizes, I just want to know to have something over another.

Comment: No :( it doesn't.

Comment: @JustAsking why doesn't the duplicate question meet your needs? This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453389/1172189 seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: The objects get a weird appearance. It just doesn't work. Edit: It doesn't work properly, i can't place in z-index: 1;

Comment: What do you mean by _i can't place in z-index: 1;_?

Comment: FWIW I voted to close your question as "unclear". You haven't described well enough how the current output differs from your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this as per you requirement shown in the [image you attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDfY.png)

Change the background colors and elements height as per your requirements

```css
body{
    margin: 0;

}
.flex-container-top {
    height: 15vh;
    background-color: red;
  }
.outside-box {
    background: #666;
    height: 85vh;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
.inside-box {
    background: #333;
    height: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 0 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-top"></div>
<div class="outside-box">
  <div class="inside-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx u so much, it's this.

Comment: If this heleped you then don't forget to mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after. When you set an element to `position: absolute`, you also need to define the width of the element. I also set the `top` and `left` to `0` so it would be to the edge of the screen.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
}

.inside-box {
  border: 15px solid rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
  height: 95vh;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 1);
}

.outside-box {
  background: rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
}

.flex-container-top {
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-top">
</div>
<div class="outside-box">
  <div class="inside-box"></div>
</div>
```