# How do you position one div on top of another?

Tags: html, css, css-position

```
.main-page {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 32px 852px 171px 0;
    padding: 21px 21px 0px 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 18px 0 rgba(35, 41, 62, 0.13);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    top: -50px;
    left: 105px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

{{start component}}
    <div class="menu"> </div>
{{end component}}
<div class="main-page">
</div>
```

We want to display the menu on top of the main page but it is appearing behind parts of the main page when scrolling. How do we put the menu on top of the main page using css?
We have tried using the z-index but that did not work. We also tried adding an opacity to change the stacking context but that did not work either.

Comment: You might share the minimal needed HTML with us here please to reproduce your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying one div on top of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453370/displaying-one-div-on-top-of-another)

Answer (score 0):

Just on top or always pinned to the top when scrolling?

I've just disabled few lines of your css and menu is on top:

```
.main-page {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    /* z-index: 999; */
    /* position: relative; */
}

.menu {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 32px 852px 171px 0;
    padding: 21px 21px 0px 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 18px 0 rgba(35, 41, 62, 0.13);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* float: right; */
    top: -50px;
    left: 105px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    /* z-index: 9999; */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k25cuax4/

Comment: always on top when scrolling

Comment: add position: fixed; to .menu class https://jsfiddle.net/xvks46ut/

Answer (score 0):

Those two elements are *siblings* in your HTML code. However, a typical relative/absolute position pair where the absolutely positioned element is on top of the other one has `position: relative` for the parent element and `position: absolute` for the child.

So you eiter should change the HTML structure accordingly (i.e. move `.menu` *into*  `.main-page`), or you can try to apply a *negative*  z-index to `.main-page` to move it to the background. (i.e. `z-index: -1`).

Comment: thanks, this does work and it puts the menu div on top of the page as desired, but now when we click on the page nothing happens, it seems like the whole page is disabled.

Comment: I suppose you used the second solution (negative z-index). Try the first one instead (making the menu a child of the page)

Comment: the menu is part of a sticky sidebar on the side of the page so I can't move it inside I don't think. any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it? In addition to that you can try to remove `position:relative` from `.main-page` or use `position: fixed` for the menu ("sticky" is still another setting, but you don't have that anywhere in your code...)